# Can Firebase support reverse DNS records?

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, reverse-dns, mautic

I'm setting up a website hosted on Firebase. Currently, I'm using the Mautic for email automation which is currently going to Spam. My technical resource told me it was because I needed to set up rDNS records.

Does anyone know if Firebase supports this? I couldn't find any answers on here or Google.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase Hosting doesn't do any DNS hosting at all.  You'll need to use some other DNS provider, which can often be the registrar of your domain.

Comment: Thanks Doug. My domain provider is Godaddy. Would I be able to change the rDNS settings there? I was informed that rDNS records would only be confirgurable by the hosting person provider not the domain provider.